# How to keep the end bone of the rig straight? What would be the right way to do it?

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics

I have this rig that I made. I was thinking that I could use some kind of IK system to make it easier to animate. But I have a problem with it. Either I'm not creating a proper IK system, or there is another issue. The thing is, I need the end bone (highlighted) to be straight and pointing up at all time. But when I use IK, it always rotate, which is not good. What would be the best way to deal with it?

[image]

Comment: there is a rotation checkbox in ik constraint that allows you to follow ik target rotation . does that help?

Comment: clicking on the rotation checkbox doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: do you targeting the right bone? you should target another bone not from this chain and not parented to these guys

Comment: Alright. That seems to work that I wanted now. But there is another issue. The start bone need to be parented to another, but because of the IK constraint, the parenting doesn't have any effect.

Comment: if you want the whole thing to move with that parent you can parent target to it. the rule is to avoid double transform so target can be parented to any other bone that is not effected by IK